# Baseline result is much better than state-of-the-art model

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, model-evaluations

I am researching about Deep Learning based Intrusion Detection System. I found a paper on a well-known journal, which is considered as a state-of-the-art method in this research area, because it got many citations. In the paper, they proposed using Inception Resnet v4 to solve the problem and got the lowest error rate, compared to other studies.

I am developing a new method using their data pre-processing idea. First, I built a baseline, which is a very simple and shallow CNN. However, it produces a very good result, which is much better than the study using Inception Resnet (approximately 1-2%).

Note that: we are using the same dataset as well as data preprocessing as they described in the paper.

In addition, I am worry about that there maybe some mistakes while preprocessing data. Therefore, I re-implemented their proposed network and run it. The re-implemented results is not much different to the reported results in paper. So I think, my preprocessing step is correct.

The paper did not compare their results with a simple CNN model. They just compared with other architectures like LSTM, ANN, and basic machine learning models.

I am quite confused now. What should I do now?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. This is not really a data science question actually. First, in case you're a PhD student, you should ask your supervisor. Then you should check thoroughly that you evaluate really in the same way as the original paper, and that you don't have any data leakage (some wrong preprocessing steps could cause this). You should probably also check some of the papers which cite the original study, it would be strange that they all missed this point. Finally if everything confirms your finding then I'd say that you should directly submit this as a paper.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I will tell to my supervisor cause I have not found any data leakage or mistakes during the process. I have a question that is it possible to submit this result as a paper, because it is not a novel idea. What I did is just verifying the result of a study.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's not a novel method, as long as you found a way to solve a problem better than the state of the art method. Even simple reproducibility studies which just confirm an existing result can often be published, and this is definitely a better contribution than a simple reproducibility study.